# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. in VB.Net Query Wizard

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
SELECT 
    e.DESCRIPTION AS [EQUIPMENT TYPE], 
    Count(e.EQNAME) AS QUANTITY,
    Sum(IIf(e.CONDITION = 'Functional', 1, 0)) AS WORKING,
    Sum(IIf(e.CONDITION = 'Non-Functional', 1, 0)) AS [NON-WORKING]
FROM EQUIPMENTS AS e
GROUP BY e.DESCRIPTION;
```

I tried using this query in VB.net TableAdapter Query Configuration wizard and an error occurs.

Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text
Error in GROUP BY clause.

This Query works well in MS Access, what's the difference from it in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I already have a solution to this problem. I just used this query as a stored query in MS-Access then used in my VB.Net Code. Thank you guys.