# Visual Studio 2013 Query editor errors and MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT
stat_number,
sqldate,
sqlvalue,
ID,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(YEAR(sqldate)= 2013, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y2013,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(YEAR(sqldate)= 2014, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y2014,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(YEAR(sqldate)= 2015, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y2015,
weekofyear(sqldate) AS `weekofyear(sqldate)`
FROM statval1
WHERE (stat_number = 495) AND (sqldate >='2013-01-01' OR sqldate <'2015-12-31')
GROUP BY weekofyear(sqldate)
ORDER BY weekofyear(sqldate)
```

It works great everywhere else EXCEPT in Visual Studio 2013 query Editor,
Does anyone knows how to make it work? or what is wrong with the query editor?

I keep getting the error:

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Error in list
>   of function arguments: 'AS' not recognized. Unable to parse query
>   text.

If i ignore the error and keep going the datagrid seems to display the correct data, but nothing shows in the charts, I get no columns at all to select the x,Y axis. I recently started learning C# in Visual studio 2013 and I am trying to recreate a software that I made in PHP/MYSQL and recreated in Object Pascal/MYSQL but this is really putting me off visual studio.

It only took a couple of weeks to create a reporting software in Lazarus, pascal programming from not knowing anything at all, and it has taking me a week just to get MYSQL server talking properly with in Visual Studio 2013 and now the query do not work, but they work perfectly fine with object-pascal, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, ETC.

Comment: start eliminating portions of the statement. figure out WHICH `=` is causing the problem. and ditto for the `as` error. I'd take a long hard look at the `as weekofyear` business. aliases are usually mean to make ugly columns easier to refer to, not uglier...

Comment: Thank you for the data, I have over 200 queries in my software, I know which '=' is causing the problem, I am looking for a way to make it work without having to rewrite all my queries as I should not have to, as they are correct when they come to MYSQL. - I want to learn C# and recreating my software is the easiest way to do it, as I already know what the code is supposed to do but I was not expecting having to learn MS SQL and change all my queries.

Answer (score 1):

The lines baffling VS2013 are the ones like this:

```
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(YEAR(sqldate)= 2013, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y2013,
```

Your query works OK otherwise in VS2013.

But, what does this query mean? Are you sure it's well formed? You're taking advantage of MySQL's nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY` in an inscrutable way. Read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

You might consider reworking this query so it's standard.

Also, this date selection logic **omits** the last day of 2015. Is that what you want?

```
 (sqldate >='2013-01-01' OR sqldate <'2015-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, and will be glad to be proven wrong but the VS 2013 query editor is geared towards MS SQL and only knows that syntax. The query is ok for MYSQL but in MS SQL you can not name a variable inside a function call.

Anyone else have any insight into this as I'm now curious as well?

Comment: I am getting the same impression about the query editor, Is there a query editor plugin for visual studio and MYSQL?

Comment: no sorry. I haven't used this combination before. i always used vs2013 with  mssql and azure sql and it was fine with that. To be fair I didn't much have the need for custom sql as I used an ORM that like Entity Framework to abstract the query creation using linq to sql or linq to entities.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is : try to remove each attributes of the select statment and test if the query is responding an error.
With this way you can locate which attribute is giving that error.

I think , but im not sure that,  the error is caused by thos : ‘ ’ 
Try to remove them as well.

Comment: Try to check this post .. He have found a solution that might work in your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141769/error-in-list-of-function-arguments-not-recognized-in-vb-net-query-wizard